# Вывод колонок одинаковой высоты

Tags: меню, html, css

Необходима шапка. Пытаюсь оформить логотип и меню в одну линию. Примерно как меню выше.
http://i.imm.io/1gAAE.png
Как осуществить?

Comment: @Ратмир Белых, Согласно правилам форума, вопросы не должны сводиться к решению либо завершению учебных заданий за учащихся. Пожалуйста, уточните, что вы сделали сами и что не получилось.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

На хэшкоде примерно так сделано:

http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/XUTk5/

Answer (score 0):

Привет,пришла мысль сделать так: http://jsfiddle.net/alpha9000/4Tynv/
Но с паддингами изображения не знаю что делать, интересный вопрос, может кто подскажет. Понятно что можно решить с 2мя блоками и абсолютны позиционированием, но мб есть вариант легче?